# How to tell when an argument is from a hardcoded number?

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, overloading

I want to be able to tell if a numeric argument passed into a function, method or class method is from a hardcoded number.

So e.g. calling

```
MyFunc(2);
```

or

```
int a = 1;
MyFunc(a);
```

Should either overload the function to allow different implementations or some way of distinguishing

```
void MyFunc(int num)
{
  if (isHardcodedNumber(num))
    doThis();
  else
    doThat();
}
```

This is a simplified version. Ideally I'd need a solution that takes a template argument and work for any built-in numeric type.

Is this possible?

Comment: That you want to do this at all is a strong indication that you're doing something wrong. Your code should *never* need to know this. You overload based on the *type* of an input, not where it came from.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; there's an upstream design decision somewhere that leads to a weird requirement. What is the underlying problem that this is intended to solve?

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to provide an optimized version of a function if the argument is a compile-time constant?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what are you trying to achieve? I've never needed to even consider this idea and I'd like to understand what triggered you thinking that you need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *sort of* do this by overloading on rvalue reference, though that will preclude you from having a value version (as that becomes ambiguous):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int&& f)
{
    std::cout << "r-value reference: " << f << '\n';
}

void f(const int& f)
{
    std::cout << "value: " << f << '\n';
}

// you can't have void f(int) as it is now ambiguous.

int main()
{
    f(1);

    int a = 2;

    f(a);

    // it can be fooled though
    f(std::move(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
r-value reference: 1
value: 2
r-value reference: 2
```

See it here:  http://ideone.com/gZoD3m

Comment: rvalue vs lvalue isn't even close to the original request.  Value known at compile time vs. unknown at compile time is either much closer or (more likely) exactly what the OP wanted but described incorrectly.  I don't know how to template for known vs. unknown at compile time, but I think it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot distinguish these two cases.

Your function simply gets a value on the stack (or in a register, depending on your processor) passed to it.

It ***cannot*** know where that value came from before it was pushed on the stack or copied to the register (unless, of course, you pass an extra parameter to indicate so).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I can think about an extremly ugly hack to achieve it. but please don't.. this is for academic discussion only.

```
bool isNumber(const char* x){
  return isdigit(x[0]);
}

#define MyFunc_t(x) MyFunc(x,#x)

void MyFunc(int x , const char* xStr){
  bool isHardcodedNumber = isNumber(xStr);
  //do...
}

MyFunc_t(4);
int x = 8;
MyFunc_t(x);
```

A template expert might be able to turn this into compile-time constant, but I won't go that far.

but anyway , please don't in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as other says - it is not advised to do this, but just to show, that it is somehow possible, but I am not sure it will be working in all cases:

First, you should know - you can test if function is called in constexpr context or not. Simply by checking its `noexcept` property - as explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

So, you can test:

```
constexpr int f_constexpr(int a)
{
   return a;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   cout << noexcept(f_constexpr(7)) << endl; // print 1
   cout << noexcept(f_constexpr(argc)) << endl; // print 0
}
```

You get `1`, then `0` from this program above.

Unfortunately, within `f_constexpr(int)` body you always get `false` - since argument `a` is not treated as const. So, seems wrong way.

But..

You can use template tag dispatching and macro - to get something working:

```
template <bool isConstexpr>
struct f_impl;

template <>
struct f_impl<false>
{
    static int f(int a)
    {
        cout << "well, I'm not constexpr f()\n";
        return a;
    }
};

constexpr int f_constexpr(int a)
{
    return a;
}

template <>
struct f_impl<true>
{
    static constexpr int f(int a)
    {
        return f_constexpr(a);
    }
};
```

And the macro definition - to be sure - you always have the same args:

```
#define f(a) f_impl<noexcept(f_constexpr(a))>::f(a)
```

So, just checking it works:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    constexpr int a = f(7);
    cout << "constexpr was called..." << endl; 
    int c = f(argc);
    cout << "non constexpr was called, I guess..." << endl; 
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << c << endl;

}
```

And [live demo](http://ideone.com/M45rJx) and output:

> constexpr was called...
>
> well, I'm not constexpr f()
>
> non constexpr was called, I guess...
>
> 7
>
> 1